# window.onresize = function { //code } doesn't seem to exeute my inner code

Tags: javascript

I'm using `window.onresize` to calculate the appropriate coordinates for my buttons on my page. The buttons are placed in the div called `<div>trinity</div>`. The coordinates of the buttons are relatively calculated according to the height and width of the "trinity" div.

The trinity div resizes correctly when the window is being resized, but the inner code of the  `window.onresize = function ()` doesn't seem to fire off. In other words my `xml_button_create(window.myValue,height,width,false)` isn't firing off. In this function I use jQuery to adjust the coordinates of my buttons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    // get HEIGHT and WIDTH of navigation div
    var height= $("#trinity").height();
    var width= $("#trinity").width();
    // CREATE BUTTONS
    xml_button_create(window.myValue,height,width,false);
};
```

Comment: Can you also share the xml_button_create() function example?

Comment: why not use css for your positioning?

Comment: In essence it is just a big function where i create the buttons in my div. When the buttons don't jet exist (window.onload) i use the function with the true parameter xml_button_create(window.myValue,height,width,true);
and with the if statement my function decides to create new buttons. 
But when the window is being resized the buttons should already exist, that is why i use the function with the false parameter.
So then the else statement fires of. There is where i use jQuerry to adjust my buttons accordingly.

Comment: For some reason even this doesn't work:
window.onresize = function ()
{window.alert("sometext");};

Comment: are you sure the code get executed ? Are you on a regular browser ? i mean your alert code *should* work.

Comment: I found the soulution to my problem.

For some reason the window.onresize function wasn't running from an external file javaScript.js , so i placed it in html code. Not it works perfectly!

Again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery to adjust the coordinates, try to use it for the eventbinding too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        alert("Resize");
    });
});
```

Otherwise have a look at this to detect resize on all html elements.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

> With jQuery resize event, you can now bind resize event handlers to elements other than window, for super-awesome-resizing-greatness!